# Different account lockout policies for different users

Tags: active-directory

I have few Organizational Units within Active Directory server, like below:

**OU1:**

- user1
- user2

**OU2:**

- user3
- user4

My goal is to configure Account Lockout Policy in different way for two existing units.
Namely first unit should have account lockout threshold, another one shouldn't have.

I've tried to create additional **Group Policy Object** for **OU1** unit with needed configuration.
But unfortunately it doesn't work. I've tried to login to many time's but account wasn't blocked.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be only one Account policy per domain and it must be configured in a GPO linked to the Domain, not to an OU. If your domain is Windows Server 2008 or higher you can implement Fine-Grained Password Policies in order to apply different Account Lockout settings to different users.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757692(v=ws.10).aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770842(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thank you a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to help...